# Axis Object - Auto interval does not have proper value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so im writing a program that requires me to build an interface where a user can enter values for the parabolic equation y = ax2 + bx + c. the user is responsible for entering the variables for a, b, c, ymax, ymin, xmax, xmin, and the # of points. I think im almost done but i keep getting the error below.

Axis Object - Auto interval does not have proper value.'

if anyone can tell me whats going wrong id be very greatful.

```
 private void GraphUpdater(double Points, int Xmin, int Xmax)//create a method to clear the points on the graph
    {
        Chart.Series[0].Points.Clear(); //clears points

        Chart.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;//sets graph type

        double Increment; //finds space between points
        Increment = (Xmax - Xmin) / Points;

        //(double x = Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum; x <= Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum; x += Increment)
        //(double x = Xmin; x <= Xmax; x += Increment)
        for (double x = Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum; x <= Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum; x += Increment)
        {
            double y;
            y = (a * x * x) + (b * x) + c;
            Chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
        }
        
    }
    private void AxisUpdater(int Xmax, int Xmin, int Ymax, int Ymin)
    {
        //output the equation
        lblEquation.Text = "y = " + a.ToString()
            + "x^2 + " + b.ToString() + "x + " + c.ToString();

        //X VALUES
        //Chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].Minimum = Xmin;
        //Chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].Maximum = Xmax;

        //Y VALUES
        //Chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].Minimum = Ymin;
        //Chart.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].Maximum = Ymax;

       Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Xmin;
       Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Xmax;

       Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = Ymin;
       Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Ymax;
    }

    private void tabGraphingCalculator_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if (tabGraphingCalculator.SelectedTab == tabGraph)//GRAPH TAB
        {
            AxisUpdater(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax); //Call UpdateAxes method first
            GraphUpdater(Points, Xmin, Xmax);
        }
    }
```

Comment: im using a tab control that has my abc values on the first tab, the min and max values on the 2nd, and the graph on tab 3. the goal is to enter the values in tab one and two and then when tab three is clicked on it will graph the function. every time i hit the graph tab the program crashes

Comment: What are you targeting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: Which line thows that error? And: What exactly is the Interval value? Note that usually dounle.NaN is the values used for 'automatic'..

Comment: Also note that controls in a hidden tab often are not updated until it is shown..

Comment: If your goal is Winforms or WPF, I can help you fix the errors.